# how to access data from multiple different database in spring boot + mssql database?

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to make a REST API for a friend with spring boot. The application has to work on multiple databases (5 to be exact, all on the same MsSQL database, same user, preconfigured to work on another app). In my application, I need to access those data to do various tasks.

So, to start I configured the application.properties file the database connection URL similar to this,

```
# JDBC properties
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=database1Name
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=pass
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
```

So this works fine for the database name I defined in the spring Datasource URL. My problem is

1. what's the best way to configure my app to work with the other 4 databases as well?
2. is there configuration to be done for each database one by one?
3. Or is it possible to use this one configured connection to get data from other databases as well in some way?

Comment: As long as the databases are on the same server and the same account can access all of them, you can use a single connection for all of them by using a three-part table name, eg `select * from db2.dbo.Table1`. You can also combine tables from multiple databases this way. This has some drawbacks though: 1) some features don't work with cross-database queries, eg transactions with in-memory tables 2) you introduce coupling between the databases.

Comment: tx @PanagiotisKanavos, your suggestion is working for me.